How to solve simultaneous icon click in adaptive card
We have an adaptive card with different icon actions, and we want to prevent simultaneous icon clicks.
We are using UpdateActivityAsync to update the card by disabling icons, but the user can still click another icon before the card updates.
We tried managing this with conversation dialog state, but both dialogs get initiated simultaneously. We also attempted to save the user dialog process in the user state, but both dialogs still initiate at the same time, and we are unable to separate the second dialog.

Is there any other option to handle simultaneous icon click.

Currently it is not possible to disable the button clicks.
